# Logar utilizando dialógo nativo do Facebook a partir de um Progressive Web App

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, facebook, pwa

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um site que utilizará o Facebook como método de autenticação. Porém, ao invéz de utilizar o dialogo web, gostaria de utilizar o diálogo nativo do Facebook no Android (ou iOS).

Pesquisei se isso era possível, e nos poucos lugares onde encontrei a resposta parece que não tem como fazer isso. Porem as respostas são um pouco antigas e penso que talvez com o crescimento dos PWAs talvez isso seja possível atualmente.

Enfim, utilizando um Progressive Web App, é possível fazer o que eu pretendo? Se não for possível, existe alguma previsão de que isso poderá existir no futuro? Os WebIntents tem algo relacionado com isso?

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Os **Intents** são ativações de aplicativos nativos através de outro aplicativo nativo. Os **WebIntents** são ativações realizadas de um site para outros, sem que essa tenha que deixar o site em que a ativação foi realizada.

O que você precisaria seria ativar as intents (nativo), já tentei realizar algo parecido, mas não continuei no projeto, entretanto tem um [link interessante](https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/) em que o autor realiza um case conforme o que você deseja.

É importante ressaltar que os Progressive Web Apps estão em crescimento e provavelmente eles realizarão interações melhores do que hacks para atingir funções nativas, entretanto por enquanto você pode esbarrar em alguns empecilhos e talvez tenha que optar por interações web ao invés de nativas.